# Linq Newbie. Can I write this Linq query more concise?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, generics

```
 Dim entName = "Some Auto Dealer"
    Dim whereEntity As Expression(Of Func(Of Entity, Boolean)) = Function(en) en.ENTY_Name = entName
    Dim login = Repository(Of Entity).Create().FindSingle(whereEntity)

    Dim whereDealer As Expression(Of Func(Of Dealer, Boolean)) = Function(dlr) dlr.Entity.Equals(login)
    Dim dealer = Repository(Of Dealer).Create().FindSingle(whereDealer)

    Dim whereContract As Expression(Of Func(Of MBI_Contract, Boolean)) = Function(c) c.Dealer.Equals(dealer) AndAlso c.Vehicle.Make.Equals(ford)
    Dim fordContractsFromPSAuto = Repository(Of MBI_Contract).Create().FindAll(whereContract).ToList()
```

How can I write this better? It works and it's pretty fast, but it seems kind of overkill to me. The FindSingle and FindAll take `Expression(Of Func(Of T, Boolean))` as an arg for the Where clause. This is my first dabble at writing Lambda expression so please forgive me if it looks bad.

Note Repository is a generic class and Create is a factory method that returns a DataContext object. This application is using LinqToSql.

Thanks for any advice.
Cheers,
~ck in San Diego

Comment: I'm not familiar with Expression, or OF Func etc, you might consider using C#, perhaps its notation for lambdas is simpler.

Comment: Yes I agree 100% the c#, c=>c.Something = someValue is very easy to use, but this particular project is written in VB.NET and converting it to C# was shot down from a dinosaur of a project manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a C# programmer, so I'm sorry if this suggestion doesn't really apply; In C#, I would typically use one line that contains the lambda and the method call; eg:

```
var login = Repository<Entity>.Create().Single(en => en.ENTY_Name == entName);
```

I think you could do something similar in VB like:

```
Dim login = Repository(Of Entity).Create().FindSingle( _
    Function(en) en.ENTY_Name = entName)
```

This probably comes down to personal preference though...

As an alternative, you could rewrite the whole thing using the query-like syntax; I don't use it very often so I can't convert your very quickly, but it'd be more like:

```
Dim contract = From c in Repository(Of MBI_Contract) _
    join d in Repository(Of Dealer) on c.Dealer equals d _
    where d.Entity.ENTY_Name = entName _
    select c
```